# Swiper: slideTo function doesn't change to the correct index

Tags: swiper.js

So I'm implementing the dots manually of Swiper. The logic is as follows: every-time the slide changes we UpdatePoints to reflect the active slide dot. And this works perfectly on Infinite Loop false option. But when I enable it doesn't work as needed, for this reason i have also implemented another method that handles when is Infite Loop.

So by default this works, all fine if i click the points they switch to the correct indexes, but when i do some dragging and arrow clicking next/right and then after that i click a dot that is not active, slideTo sets the index of the slider sometimes one plus or minus and messes it up for some reasons. And makes the points not functional.

I run the function only when the index changes, but I'm confused and don't get what is going on and why is this happening when i drag sometimes or arrow click.

Below is the code that updates the points and the listeners:

```js
import { UseState } from '@/utils'
import { SF_ATTR_NAMES, SF_ATTR_VALUES } from '@/constants'

let PREVIOUS_INDEX: null | number = null

const UpdatePoints = (
    slider_id: string,
    active_point: HTMLElement,
    inactive_point: HTMLElement,
    active_point_counter: HTMLElement,
    inactive_point_counter: HTMLElement,
    currentSlide?: number
) => {
    const { Slideflow, Current } = UseState(slider_id)

    const slideLength = Current?.slides?.length
    const points_container = Current?.slider?.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE}='${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINTS}']`)

    if (points_container) {
        while (points_container.firstChild) points_container.removeChild(points_container.firstChild)
        
        for (let i = 0; i < slideLength; i++) {
            if (active_point_counter && inactive_point_counter && active_point && inactive_point) {
                const new_point = currentSlide === i ? active_point.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement : inactive_point.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement
                const new_point_counter = currentSlide === i ? active_point_counter.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement : inactive_point_counter.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement

                while (new_point_counter.firstChild) new_point_counter.removeChild(new_point_counter.firstChild)
                while (new_point.firstChild) new_point.removeChild(new_point.firstChild)
                    
                new_point.addEventListener('click', () => Slideflow.slideTo(i))
                new_point_counter.innerText = String(i + 1)

                new_point.appendChild(new_point_counter)
                points_container.appendChild(new_point)
            }

            else if (active_point && inactive_point) {
                const new_point = currentSlide === i ? active_point.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement : inactive_point.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement

                new_point.addEventListener('click', () => Slideflow.slideTo(i))
                points_container.appendChild(new_point)
            }
        }
    }
}

const Points = (slider_id: string): void => {
    const { Configs, Slideflow, Current } = UseState(slider_id)

    const points_container = Current?.slider?.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE}='${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINTS}']`)

    if (Configs?.Points && points_container) {
        const active_point = points_container.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE}='${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINT_ACTIVE}']`) as HTMLElement
        const inactive_point = points_container.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE}='${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINT_INACTIVE}']`) as HTMLElement
        const active_point_counter = points_container.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE} = '${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINT_TEXT_ACTIVE}']`) as HTMLElement
        const inactive_point_counter = points_container.querySelector(`[${SF_ATTR_NAMES.TYPE} = '${SF_ATTR_VALUES.POINT_TEXT_INACTIVE}']`) as HTMLElement

        const index = Slideflow.realIndex

        if (!Configs.InfiniteLoop) UpdatePoints(
            slider_id,
            active_point,
            inactive_point,
            active_point_counter,
            inactive_point_counter,
            index
        )

        if (!Configs.InfiniteLoop) Slideflow.on('slideChange', () => {
            const index = Slideflow.activeIndex

            if (PREVIOUS_INDEX !== index) {
                PREVIOUS_INDEX = index
                
                UpdatePoints(
                    slider_id,
                    active_point,
                    inactive_point,
                    active_point_counter,
                    inactive_point_counter,
                    index
                )
            }
        })

        Slideflow.on('slideChange', () => {
            const index = Slideflow.realIndex
        
            if (PREVIOUS_INDEX !== index) {
                PREVIOUS_INDEX = index
        
                UpdatePoints(
                    slider_id,
                    active_point,
                    inactive_point,
                    active_point_counter,
                    inactive_point_counter,
                    index
                )
            }
        })
    }
}

export default Points
```

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to fix it.

The problem was `slideTo` as also mentioned, it doesn't work with Infinite Loop.  Instead I used `slideToLoop()` and it fixed the issue.